# Authorize to Apple Music via Facebook Messenger In-App Browser

Tags: apple-music, apple-musickit, apple-musickit-js

We're using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/musickitjs to authorize Apple music, on Desktop it opens a new window to authorize to apple.

But It's NOT working on mobile In-App Browser (both iOS & Android), probably because on mobile messenger, it's not possible to allow the opening of multiple windows.

Are we missing something here? Any workaround for it?

Has anyone done that?

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/117058